# c++ namespace export

Tags: c++, export, namespaces

Is there a way in C++ to create an anonymous namespace, and only export a single function out of it?

I want something like:

```
namespace {
  void Bar() {}
  void Foo() { Bar(); }
}
```

Now, I want to somehow access to `Foo()` yet make sure there's no way to touch `Bar()`

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by 'export a function'?

Comment: I understand "export" here as "having external linkage" in the context of the compilation unit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want `Foo()` to have external linkage, you should declare it in a header file:

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

void Foo();

#endif
```

Now everyone can see and call `Foo()`

But in Foo.cpp:

```
#include "Foo.h"

namespace {
    void Bar(){ }
}

void Foo(){ Bar(); }
```

Now, as long as you control the source file Foo.cpp, no one can change access to `Bar()`

Comment: +1 good answer & model example, it deserves some more upvotes

Answer (score 7):

If you want to export the function, you'll have to put it outside the anonymous namespace.

```
namespace {
  void Bar() {};
};
void Foo() { Bar(); };
```

Comment: The anonymous namespace is meant to not leave the cpp (obj) file. So export and anonymous are different sides of the coin.

Comment: This doesn't restrict access to `Bar()`

Comment: It does restrict access to Bar() from other compilation units.

Answer (score 2):

You could place them in different header files and make sure clients only get the header file that declares `Foo()`. However, you cannot implement `Foo()` inline with that solution.

Answer (score 1):

why not

```
namespace {
  void Bar() {};
};
void Foo() { Bar(); };
```

?

an anonymous namespace is accessible from the file you created it in

Answer (score 0):

Define Bar as a global static function in the CPP file that contains the function body for Foo.

Edit: Its worth noting that this will only cause a link time error.
Edit2: And I ran a quick test and it seems you can't extern to an anonymous namespace.
Edit3:

Something like this would seem sensible (and lose the namespace)

```
static void Bar()
{
}

void Foo()
{
    Bar();
}
```

You can now "extern void Foo();" but if you try the same with Bar then the linker will fail as Bar no longer has external linkage.

Comment: This use of static is deprecated in C++ (see 7.3.1.1/2 of either the current Standard or the C++0x draft).